# fetch price of a movie from different OTT Plateform

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-package

Suppose I have a movie name or  movie detail got from IMBD API. I want to check the price of movie in different OTT Plateforms (or in every Plateforms where the movie is available) if there is package in react or node please let me know.

I only have a movie name suppose john wick chapter 4. I want this movie pricing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.